# How to publish my PhD as a monograph when examiners are unable to oversee the process?

Tags: publications, phd, paper-submission, publishers, monograph

Before my viva (as they call it in the UK) one of my supervisors strongly hinted that one of my examiners would likely be interested in supervising me with the writing of a monograph. Three months after my PhD was awarded, I decided to contact both examiners and both responded that they did not feel qualified: one does not hold a doctorate, the other's main disciplinary area is outside my own.

Fair enough.

I was given your typical stock advice to publish and review but my heart is still set on publishing a monograph.

There are a couple of professors throughout the UK and North America whom I am keen to contact as potential supervisors for my project on the basis of our  shared research affinities. Do I just send them an email? What is the protocol?
This newbie academic does not want to commit any faux-pas!

Is a monograph or book of some sort an independent endeavour?.

Sigh.... post-PhD distress

Comment: Are you talking about PhD thesis or just papers?

Comment: Am I missing something here? How can these be your examiners if they are not qualified for this?

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but can't your former supervisors help you with that?

Comment: The question is very confusing.  Monographs/books can be solo or co-authored of course.  How exactly is the monograph related to your thesis?  Why do you still need a supervisor?

Comment: I finished my PhD a few months ago. In the UK, a monograph stems from your PhD dissertation.  Based on my conversation with my supervisor, I apparently need a 'supervsior ' to guide me throughout the process of writing a monograph.  @Kimball: good point but my supervisors did not offer to but instead hinted that the examiner would be interested to do so

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft : one examiner does not hold a PhD but is part of the university faculty.  The other specialized in my secondary discipline.

Comment: It's news to me that anyone needs to supervise your writing a book in the first place. Is this field dependent or something?

Comment: It would help people to give more relevant answers if you specified your discipline, or at least whether you are are in the arts, social sciences, natural sciences, etc. For instance, your claim that "in the UK, a monograph stems from your PhD dissertation" is _not_ usually the case in e.g. mathematics

Comment: How can someone not holding a doctorate examine a PhD?

Comment: @Roland: Have a look at this example (in German)thehttps://tu-dresden.de/mn/postgraduales/promotion/promotionsordnung - it just says that "usually the majority of reviewers shall be university lecturers" and "the PhD commission  shall usually be lecturers of *this* university". If the faculty commission that oversees the PhD procedures think someone suited they can nominate them regardless of formal qualifications (they probably need to document well why exactly, but it is possible). The point here is that this person is considered fully qualified, though (by that faculty commission).

Comment: BTW: strictly speaking, you don't need to hold a doctorate to become a professor - you "just" need to prove research capabilities that are equivalent to doctorate and habilitation (plus a few more things such as ability to teach).

Comment: @cbeleites A "Hochschullehrer" [is at least a "Juniorprofessor"](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/hrg/__42.html). But you are right, they allow "qualified scientists". I don't have the legal expertise to know if you can be qualified without a phd. A junior or tenured professor without phd is such a rare [exception](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/hrg/__44.html) that it's not worth discussing.

Comment: I'm in a field where monographs are the norm an cumulative dissertations the exception. Neither I nor anyone I know needed a supervisor to publish their PhD dissertation as monograph. You just send a polished book proposal and perhaps sample chapter(s) to the publisher you are interested in and hope for the best. My experience is in Germany and Austria with British and US publishers.

Answer (score 2):

Be upfront and honest, and ask!

Make contact with these select few. Explain that you've received interest in producing a monograph, but those doing so later declined their support because their qualifications or subject knowledge are, described much lesd tactfully than you should, inadequate.

Describe your reasons for contacting them in particular - yes, personalise these requests. Ask if they are available to lend support, and whether they would desire to do so. Don't send a copy of your thesis, but make it clear that you will on request, that is, if they don't indicate that they looked it up already.

If you get declined, thank them for their answer, and for any helpful critique or advice they give. If they accept, discuss with your university to see what support you can get from them -  if you have their backing already, this is a good thing to mention in your approach to potential collaborators.